# Stabiliser group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symplectic-linear-algebra, classical-groups, orbit-stabilizer

Let $G=\operatorname{Sp}_{2r}(2)$. There are two orbits of $G$ on the natural $G$-set, one having the identity, the other having all the remaining elements. What is the subgroup of $G$ that stabilizes a nontrivial element of the $G$-set?

This might have no general answer or I'm being silly.. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a parabolic subgroup. (In symplectic groups, parabolic subgroups are stabilizers of totally isotropic subspaces.)

Say $v$ is a nonzero vector. Then you can extend this to a symplectic basis $v, e_1, ... e_{r-1}, f_{r-1}, ..., f_{1}, w$ where $\{v,w\}$ and $\{e_i, f_i\}$ are hyperbolic pairs.

Wrt. this basis, in the stabilizer of $v$ you have a Levi subgroup $$L = \{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & A & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} : A \in Sp(2r-2,2) \}$$

and a unipotent radical $$U = \{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & * & * \\ 0 & I & * \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \}$$

which has order $2^{2r-1}$. The stabilizer of $v$ in $Sp(2r,2)$ equals a semidirect product $U \rtimes L$.

So the structure is $2^{2r-1} : Sp(2r-2,2)$ as noted in the answer by Derek Holt.

Note that this also works for $r = 1$, in which case $L$ is trivial and $U$ is generated by $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: I see. So the stabilizer of $v$ must simultaneously stabilize $w$ because they are in a pair, right?

Comment: Also may I ask the definition for the quadratic form for "totally isotropic"? What I learned is that quadratic form is associated with a symmetric bilinear form whereas the bilinear form on a symplectic basis is alternating... Thx.

Comment: For the first question, no. See the answer.

Comment: Usually totally isotropic means a subspace $W$ such that $b(v,w) = 0$ for all $v,w \in W$. Here $b$ is the bilinear form.  With a quadratic form $Q$ you also have "totally singular" meaning $W$ with $Q(v) = 0$ for all $v \in W$.

Comment: Sorry, I suddenly got confused. Why the order of $U$ is $2^{2r-1}$? The $I$ is $2r-2$ by $2r-2$, right?

Comment: @scsnm: Yes, but the first row of a matrix $u \in U$ determines the rest of the entries of $u$. (Using the fact that $u$ leaves the bilinear form invariant.)

Answer (score 1):

It's a subgroup with structure $2^{2r-1}:{\rm Sp}(2(r-1),2)$, where the $2^{2r-1}$ denotes an elementary abelian group, and the extension is (I think) split.

The corresponding $(2r-1)$-dimensional module for ${\rm Sp}(2(r-1),2)$ over ${\mathbb F}_2$ is uniserial with a (minimal and maximal)  submodule of dimension $1$.

Comment: I don't follow the end of the answer - isn't the $Sp(2r-2,2)$ completely reducible?

Comment: @spin It's completely reducible as a subgroup of ${\rm Sp}(2r,2)$, but not in its action on the subgroup $2^{2r-1}$ of the stabilizer of a vector in the natural action.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, I agree.